# Is it possible to update the preinstalled versions of both MySQL and PHP in OS X?

Tags: upgrade, mysql, php

I'm running 10.6.4 and PHP reports itself as version 5.3.2 (5.3.3 is available) and mySQL reports version 5.1.45 (5.1.51 is available)

I know they are minor releases but is it possible to easily update either of these?  If so, any hints or pointers as to how?

Comment: Do you have MySQL installed by default? It's not on my system, even though I do have devel tools installed.

Comment: Now that you mention it I'm thinking I had to install it on my MBP but it was installed on our server.  mySQL should be available at http://www.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/

Comment: @Peter Štibraný: MySQL is pre-installed with Mac OS X Server but not Client

Comment: @Chealion: ah, didn't know that. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Briefly; no there is no easy way to update them. (Assuming that compiling from source is not considered easy)

I would strongly caution against modifying the system installed versions as you're likely to have your updated versions broken when Apple issues an update that updates them. (Usually Security Updates and has bitten some users/sysadmins when Perl has been updated)

If you wanted to update them it's a matter of downloading the source files and installing it over top of the provided versions.

As a reasonable alternative I recommend installing your own managed version of PHP and MySQL into `/usr/local` or using your packaging software of choice (MacPorts, Fink or Homebrew) or prepared installer (eg. MySQL's .pkg installer that installs into `/usr/local`).