# Where can I find a list of MAMPs?

Tags: apache, mysql, php

I'm looking for a MAMP packaging = Apache + MySQL + PHP bundled together for Mac OS X (which is my OS). Where can I find it? Is there an "official" site where I can download it from?

[ I know that there are Apache and PHP shipped with Mac OS X, but I don't want to use them, because it seems that if I do it, and later upgrade them, I may have trouble in the case Apple provides a system update which reverts or conflicts with my "manual" upgrade. Can you confirm that? Here is the link: [1](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2824/is-it-possible-to-update-the-preinstalled-versions-of-both-mysql-and-php-in-os-x)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a look at [MAMP](http://mamp.info/en/index.html) (there's a free and commercial version)

> MAMP is installed in the typical Mac fashion: very easily. MAMP will not compromise any existing Apache installation already running with your OS X. You can install Apache, PHP and MySQL without starting a script or having to change any configuration files!
>
> **Philosophy**: MAMP was created primarily as a PHP development environment for Macintosh computer and should therefore not be used as Live Webserver for the Internet. In this case, we recommend that you use Mac OS X server with the provided Apache or a Linux server.

[image: MAMP screenshot]

Included programs & libraries

- Apache 2.0.63
- MySQL 5.1.44
- PHP 5.2.13 & 5.3.2
- APC 3.1.3
- eAccelerator 0.9.6
- XCache 1.2.2 & 1.3.0
- phpMyAdmin 3.2.5
- Zend Optimizer 3.3.9
- SQLiteManager 1.2.4
- Freetype 2.3.9
- t1lib 5.1.2
- curl 7.20.0
- jpeg 8
- libpng-1.2.42
- gd 2.0.34
- libxml 2.7.6
- libxslt 1.1.26
- gettext 0.17
- libidn 1.15
- iconv 1.13
- mcrypt 2.6.8
- YAZ 4.0.1 & PHP/YAZ 1.0.14

Comment: this is really only for development and testing purposes only, the site states not recommended for production use

Comment: Yes, true. Forgot to mention that - added a paragraph to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few, but my favourite is Zend's own, fully integrated hassle free controller

[Zend Server Community Edition](http://www.zend.com/en/products/server-ce/)

Comment: It says "not for production use". :/ Any others?

Comment: From the zend website. "Zend Server Community Edition is a fast and reliable PHP application stack. It is completely free, and you can use it in development, testing and production. Windows, Linux, Mac OS X and IBM i are supported."